# Drag and Drop clone object background

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop

I am trying to implement drag and drop of HTML5 with a circle into another. When I drag the circle, it appears to have a clone of the dragable object(a circle with less opacity). When the circles are wrapped in a container that has a background color(green in my case), the dragged circle gets it's background and when dragged it is surrounded with a green square that is underlined from it's parent container.
My goal is to be able to drag the circles inside the container, but without the green square that is around them.

Here is my code in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2skzxn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is here:
https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/788

in short - it seems to be a problem chrome. To fix this, add "transform: translate(0,0)" to your circle's style:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    transform: translate(0,0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is setting a custom **ghost image** when using **drag and drop**.

Try This :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-circle',
  templateUrl: './circle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./circle.component.css']
})
export class CircleComponent implements OnInit {
  static id=0;
  constructor( private elementRef: ElementRef ) {}
  data = '' + (CircleComponent.id++);
  isHoveringAboveArea = false;


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  handleDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
    console.log(event);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.data);
    let crt = this.elementRef.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    crt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0); // Here's the magic line
  }

  drop (event: DragEvent) {
    console.log("droped " + event.dataTransfer.getData('text') + " over " + this.data);
  }

  onDragLeave(event) {
    this.isHoveringAboveArea = false;
  }

  dragover(event: DragEvent) {
    // console.log("over: ", event);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.isHoveringAboveArea = true;
  }
}
```